# JPanel not showing when added to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I am creating a GUI in java. Currently i have an empty JFrame and am trying to add a JPanel to it. The JPanel contains buttons, text etc. However none of this is being displayed. My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class memoDisplayUI { 


JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTextArea jTextBox = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                memoDisplayUI frame = new memoDisplayUI();
                frame.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public memoDisplayUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 270, 400);
    frame.setUndecorated(true); //REMOVES MENU BAR
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JLabel lblMemos = new JLabel("MEMOS");
    lblMemos.setForeground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    lblMemos.setFont(new Font("Moire", Font.BOLD, 30));
    lblMemos.setBounds(16, 16, 234, 37);
    panel.add(lblMemos);
    
    JButton button = new JButton("");
    button.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    button.setBounds(7, 350, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button);
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("back.png"));
    
    JButton button_1 = new JButton("");
    button_1.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    button_1.setBounds(113, 350, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button_1);
    button_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Edit.png"));
    
    JButton button_2 = new JButton("");
    button_2.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    button_2.setBounds(220, 350, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button_2);
    button_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("memo.png"));
    
    JButton btnExit = new JButton("");
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnExit.setBorder(null);
    btnExit.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Exit.jpg"));
    btnExit.setBounds(216, 19, 40, 40);
    panel.add(btnExit);
    
    jTextBox = new JTextArea();
    scroll.setViewportView(jTextBox); // add scroll panel
    jTextBox.setTabSize(4);
    jTextBox.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextBox.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192));
    jTextBox.setBounds(8, 60, 255, 286);
    panel.add(jTextBox);
    
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
}
}
```

Could someone please advise as to why this is?

Thanks very much :)

### Edit

From a few tweaks to the code, it appears this is the desired layout (in a non-resizable GUI).

[image: Memos GUI]

Comment: Hint: Are your components being added to the frame or the **panel**? What's going on with your frame, that should rather be going on with the panel?

Comment: That being said, you should really look into using a [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and avoiding null layouts. Let the layouts do the sizing and placing for you ;)

Comment: I think you used null to get a "place it wherever fits"? Then use a FlowLayout :)

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: BTW - I edited an image into the question.  Is that the basic layout you are trying to achieve?  If so, a better question would be "How to layout this GUI?" (so long as you provide an attempt).

Answer (score 2):

I think you used null to get a "place it wherever fits"? Then use a FlowLayout

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

That should fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone please advise as to why this is?

Using `null` layouts and not calling `pack()`.

The image I edited into the question was obtained as a screenshot of the GUI after I had commented out the call to `setUndecorated(true)` and dragged it a little bigger.  Doing so causes the JRE to validate the component structure (what `pack()` would do) and thereby make the components appear.

---

As I mentioned in a comment:

> ..a better question would be *"How to layout this GUI?"* (so long as you provide an attempt)

And that leads me to my first comment.  (Now in longer form)

Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>1</sup>, along with layout padding & borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556)<sup>2</sup>.

1. [image]
2. [image]

---

So coming back to:

> (so long as you provide an attempt)

Look over those two examples to see how they work, then attempt to combine some layouts and padding to create a frame that can then be packed to reduce to the natural size.

And a tip the the `JTextArea`.  Suggest a size in columns x rows combined with the `Font` size.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer, however I'm still struggling on how to implement this. Thanks :)

Comment: If that is your question ..ask a **new** question.  This question, specifically, "Could someone please advise as to why this is?" has been answered IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove/comment this line from the above code  at line number 46.

```
// frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

It should work fine..

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

with

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Good luck.

**Edit:** For future reference, to decide which `LayoutManager` should be used in your case, you should refer to this [**Visual Guide to LayoutManagers**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: I added some code he might need if he decides to use this.

Comment: Thanks but, all the items in the panel are out of alignment

Comment: In that case, you should use `panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` as well.

Answer (score 1):

1: You should never call setLayout(null).
2: Try frame.validate() to layout the components with your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shoul replace :

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

by

```
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

Hope it helped